# Is it correct to use the 'at'?

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence, is it grammatically correct to use the  'at'?

> The temperature is at zero degree Fahrenheit for frozen food.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it should say "zero **degrees** Fahrenheit".

But as far as the use of "at", there are circumstances where it could be correct and others where it would be incorrect, depending on context.

If, for example, you were explaining what the correct temperature is for storing frozen foods, then you would not use "at". You would say "*The (correct) temperature **is** zero degrees Fahrenheit for frozen food.*"

But if you were describing the *current temperature* of some frozen foods, you might say *"The temperature **is at** zero degrees Fahrenheit for the frozen foods."* In this latter case, "at" is used to describe a **current state or condition**.